# Why does NSScrollView display a white track?

Tags: swift, macos, scrollbar, nsscrollview

I am programming with **macos**, in **swift**.  I have a few paragraphs of text (Lopem Ipsum - to test) inside a **scroll view**.  Also a title, which is a NSTextView, positioned above.

When I present it in a **popover**, all looks fine.

[image: present it in a popover]

However in another part of the project, I present a the same contents (using a copy of the same layout code - below), but this time in a **modal window**.

[image: in a modal window]

It has a ugly white **track**!  That must be connected to the **scroll view**, since it only appears when I set the vertical scrollbar - `hasVerticalScroller`, which is necessary because I want vertical scrolling.  As it should, the **knob** highlights on mouse-hover and it scolls properly.

It probably would be fine with a solid white background.  But that's not what I want!  Thus I have the setting `scrollView.drawsBackground = false`.

I've tried: `scrollView.verticalScroller?.highlight(false)`;    `scrollView.verticalScroller?.wantsLayer = true`; `scrollView.verticalScroller?.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear.cgColor` - no luck!

Even tried with only one paragraph (ie. no scroll), still the same.

[image]

I am using code similar to this:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    let scrollView = NSScrollView()
    let textView = NSTextView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textView.maxSize = NSSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        textView.autoresizingMask = .width
        textView.isVerticallyResizable = true
        textView.textContainer?.widthTracksTextView = true

        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.documentView = textView

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
}
```

What can I do to have a *clear* (no background) **track** on the scrollbar?

Comment: The Close button also looks different.

Comment: Maybe related: [NSScrollView in a popup became transparent under MacOS Mojave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52824161/nsscrollview-in-a-popup-became-transparent-under-macos-mojave)

Comment: Maybe related: [NSTableview inside NSPopover looks different as standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47500931/nstableview-inside-nspopover-looks-different-as-standalone)

Comment: @Willeke Just to let you know: The 2nd article helped, I set the entire view to .vibrantLight and now it looks the same (ie. transparent).  However it didn't change the button at all. Judging with articles, I think this is Apple bug!

Answer (score 0):

scrollView.scrollerStyle = .overlay

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Please provide an explanation of how your answer solves the problem. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for more info